# My console.log keeps saying NaN is false while it isn't

Tags: javascript, html, nan

So I have this code and when the user types a number it should log "this is a valid number" in the console and else it should log "this is not a valid number". But my code keeps logging "this is a valid number". And I have to use isNaN.

Please be easy on me, I'm just starting JavaScript.

This is my HTML code:

```
  <!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Postcode</title>


    <script src="postcode.js">
 </script>
</head>

<body>

<form class="form">
  <label for="postcode">Postcode: </label>
  <input type="text" id="postcode">
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

And this is my JavaScript code:

```
window.addEventListener("load", init);

  function init() {
    alert("Content loaded");

    var nameInput = document.getElementById('postcode');

    document.querySelector('form.form').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {

      //prevent the normal submission of the form
      e.preventDefault();



        if (nameInput === isNaN || nameInput === "") {
          console.log("this is not a valid number!");}
        else if (nameInput !==  isNaN) {
          console.log("this is a valid number!");}

    });

    }
```

Comment: I think you want [Validate decimal numbers in JavaScript - IsNumeric()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-decimal-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric)

Comment: `nameInput` is a **DOM element**. It will never be equal to the function `isNaN` nor to the string `''`.

Comment: Always read documentation if you are using something unfamiliar: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `isNaN(...)` to check if a something is Not A Number:

```
isNaN('a'); // true
```

And also `nameInput` refers to a DOM node, get the value (or innerHTML):

```
isNaN(nameInput.value)
```

And your full code:

```
window.addEventListener("load", init);

function init() {
    var nameInput = document.getElementById('postcode');
    document.querySelector('.form').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!nameInput.value || isNaN(nameInput.value)) {
            console.log("this is not a valid number!");}
        else {
            console.log("this is a valid number!");}
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Is there also a possibility to check if that valid number is bigger than 1000 and smaller than 9999?

Comment: `if (nameInput.value > 1000 && nameInput.value < 9999)` ?

Comment: great, thank you! I always forget to put '.value' behind it

Comment: Store it in a variable an call it `nameValue` ? `var nameValue = nameInput.value;`

Answer (score 2):

There's something in javascript called [`NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN) *(Not A Number)*, then there's a function that checks if something is `NaN` appropriately called [`isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN).

You're checking if your variable is the exact same as the `isNaN` function, which of course it's not, as `nameInput` is an object, or more correctly a HTML input element.

What you want is probably to get the value of the input, and check if it's "Not A Number", or just an empty string *(which seems like an uneccessary check here)*

```
if (isNaN(nameInput.value) || nameInput.value === "") {
```

Comment: `isNaN('\t') == false`. But a tab is not a number. Neither `isNaN` nor `Number.isNaN` can validate numeric strings.

Comment: @Oriol: That's because `Number('\t')` is `0`. Whitespace has to be treated separately (trimming the string should work too though). But very good point. I wonder if the OP considers `'0xA5'` to be a valid input.

Comment: How would you get a tab as an inputs value ?

Comment: @adeneo Probably not with the tab key, but for example by pasting.

Answer (score 0):

isNaN is a function. If you do `nameInput === isNaN`, you check if `nameInput` is pointing to the function `isNaN`. 
What you want to do, is to call the function: `isNaN(nameInput)`.

Also nameInput is a [HTML DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input). You first have to get the value from it: `nameInput.value`

Just do:

```
if (isNaN(nameInput.value)) {
    console.log("this is not a valid number!");}
else {
    console.log("this is a valid number!");
}
```